# Parse JSON in Dhall

Tags: json, dhall

Dhall is famous for *generating* JSON, namely from `input.dhall` to `output.json`. Is it possible to write a “JSON transformer” in Dhall, namely “`input.json` + `rules.dhall` → `output.json`”? It still sounds functional (two input and one output), but I wonder whether Dhall is the right tool for this purpose. I know how to import the JSON file as bytes, but I hear that Dhall intentionally avoids supporting any text parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Dhall does not support a way to import JSON expressions at runtime.  You can only conver them to Dhall using the `json-to-dhall` utility.

Comment: That’s what I thought (see my own answer), but thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing JSON in Dhall, I guess the idiomatic way is to generate Dhall code from the JSON, which can be done by the `json-to-dhall` utility from the [`dhall-json` package](https://repology.org/project/dhall-json). Let’s call the generated file `generated.dhall`. After that, we can create `result.dhall` with

```
let original = ./generated.dhall
in original ⫽ { someKey = "new value" }
```

Then we can convert the data back to JSON with `dhall-to-json`.